# Correct directory path in virtual machine

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-machine, filepath, parallels

I've recently started using Windows 7 from my Mac on Parallels, and I'm having some issues finding the correct directory path for a file. In OS X, the path for a file named TestFile.txt is /Users/MyAccount/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/FTP Process/TestFile.txt. In Windows, however, the path is \psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FTP Process\TestFile.txt.

I am trying to use the C# File.Exists() method with a string literal of this file path. I've tried using both of the above paths as the parameter of the method, and both return false when I expect one or the other to return true. Does anyone know what the correct string for this path would be? Thanks.

Comment: What about some code to see what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Differences in the path of special folders on various host operating systems are encapsulated via [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can get the actual path of a special folder with [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try something like

```
string documentsPath = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

In your case, that should return

> /Users/MyAccount/Documents/

under OS/X, and

> \psf\Home\Documents

under Windows (I'm guessing there will also be a drive letter under Windows, but not exactly sure how Parallels works).